# tmux: set pane title to currently running command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tmux

How can I make tmux to set `pane_title` automatically to currently running command?

Actually the setting `automatic-rename` is just what I want for `pane_title`, but for it's only for `window_name`.

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747952/pane-title-in-tmux) answered on StackOverflow. Since you want the current command, rather than the last command, the easiest thing to do is use a wrapper function to update the pane title.

```
panewrap () { printf "\033]2;%s\033\\" "$1"; "$@"; }
```

By prefixing all your commands with calls to *panewrap*, your tmux status bar will be updated before each command is run.

Comment: This is almost what I want. This the last executed command. I need the currently running command. For example when I execute python repl.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Where would one put this code?

Comment: @oneself `panewrap` definition would go in your `~/.bash_profile` the panewrap usage would be in front of EVERY command inside tmux: `panewrap tail my.log` or `panewrap echo hello` or whatever.